# HTTP url for clone is wrong in GitLab

Tags: nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

**PROBLEM**:

When I create a repository in GitLab, it shows different HTTP URL and SSH URL of the repository by some reason.
eg)

```
HTTP: http://anotherexample.com/myrepo.git
```

```
SSH: git@gitlab.example.com/myrepo.git
```

My gitlab URL is: **https: //gitlab.example.com**, so SSH is correct and HTTP is wrong.

( **anotherexample.com** is the URL of my server before I set DNS.)

---

I looked at 
*/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml*, then found:

```
# 1. GitLab app settings
# ==========================
host: anotherexample.com
port: 80
https: false

ssh_host: gitlab.example.com
```

then I manually changed this *host* and it's temporarily solved.

However, **gitlab.yml** will be updated when I do **gitlab-ctl reconfigure**.

---

**QUESTION**:
How can I set this host name for HTTP in **/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**
?

I've already had two lines below:

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'gitlab.example.com'
```

but it seems not work for HTTP url.

---

My GitLab version : 8.8.3
My server : CentOS 6.8 + nginx 1.10.1

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this a programming question? Please, [see this page in order to see the appropriate topics for StackOverflow!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) :)

Answer (score 7):

For people like me who had entirely the wrong URL you will need to update just

```
external_url "http://gitlab.example.com"
```

in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and then run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

for the changes to take effect. You can read more in the [official docs here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html)

Answer (score 5):

It's solved.

I just added the line below in **/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_host'] = 'gitlab.example.com'
```

Comment: I concur, worked for me too with the omnibus package for Debian.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still here in 2019 trying to get this to work (with docker for example) set the hostname on the machine (/etc/hosts or hostnamectl or -h when using docker).